# Uncaught module jqueryify not found

Tags: javascript, node.js, commonjs, spine.js

### My situation

I'm checking out spine.js for a web application I'm thinking of writing. I've read all the documentation and gone through all the examples. Now I'm trying to run the spine.contacts example project on my own Windows 7 laptop.

I'm running node v0.6.6 for Windows

### What I've done

- Installed node
- Installed spine, spine-app and hem through npm
- Extracted spine.contacts in a folder
- Run `npm install .` inside the folder, which created the node_modules folder with a bunch of directories inside, including jqueryify
- Run `hem server` to start the test server
- Basically followed all the instructions to the letter

### The problem

Running the application in Chrome (http://localhost:9294), JavaScript throws an exception at line 9 in index.html (I've included index.html below). It reads "Uncaught module jqueryify not found". I know the jqueryify dependency was installed by npm earlier, but I tried removing that line anyway and linking in jQuery manually. Now I got the error "Uncaught module index not found" in application.js. That certainly isn't a dependency error, since the index.js file is local and it's the main script file in the project.

So it seems there's a problem with the require function. I've Googled a lot and nothing I've found has indicated that spine.js shouldn't work on Windows.

**Any ideas?**

---

### Some links

- [The GIT page for spine.contacts](https://github.com/maccman/spine.contacts)
- [A demo of the exact same project on herokuapp.com](http://spine-contacts.herokuapp.com/)

---

*index.html:*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <title>App</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/application.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8">
  <script src="/application.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    var jQuery  = require("jqueryify"); // I'm line 9!!
    var exports = this;
    jQuery(function(){
      var App = require("index");
      exports.app = new App({el: $("#article")});      
    });
  </script>  
</head>
<body>
  <header id="header"><h1>Spine Contacts</h1></header>
  <article id="article"></article>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hem is not supported on Windows. I found myself in the same situation and tried the same approaches.

More info here: https://github.com/maccman/hem/issues/23

Comment: Solid answer. I hate it when node.js stuff isn't platform independent

Answer (score 1):

Try inserting that before line 9:

```
for(var winPath in require.modules)
{
path = winPath.replace(/\\/g, '/'); 
path = path.match('/node_modules/') ? path.split('/node_modules/')[1] : path;
path = path.match('/app/') ? path.split('/app/')[1] : path;
require.modules[path] = require.modules[winPath];
}
```

I think a fix will be there soon.

Comment: [The official comment](https://github.com/maccman/hem/issues/23#issuecomment-3584464) by the author is that he's not going to bother. Also you have a regex error in your code that's screwing up the syntax highlighting :-P

Comment: I fixed the regex ;). You don't really need the author to bother, node apps should be OS agnostic