# Spine.js mobile (phonegap) ReferenceError Jqueryify

Tags: javascript, node.js, cordova, spine.js

My problem is very much like the Hem on windows problem: [Uncaught module jqueryify not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8705580/uncaught-module-jqueryify-not-found)

I can't deploy my spine mobile app to a android mobile devise using phonegap, it works perfectly in a browser (linux) but whenever I run it through eclipse on a android devise (various versions tested) I recieve:

```
06-17 18:39:36.878: E/Web Console(5976): ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require at file:///android_asset/www/index.html:9
```

Which is referencing:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <title>App</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/application.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8">
  <script src="/application.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    var jQuery  = require("jqueryify"); //REFERENCED LINE 9
    var exports = this;
    jQuery(function(){
      var App = require("index");
      exports.app = new App({el: $("body")});      
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

I have installed the dependencies through npm and also built it using Hem, I'm kind of lost to what the problem might be.

Any ideas why this might be happening?

** **EDIT** **

The problem was the .js file was not being found, needed:

```
<script src="./application.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

NOTICE THE '.' in the javascript file src att.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error specifically means that the `require` function is undefined when it executes your inline script. Since `require` isn't a built-in part of browser JavaScript, that means whatever code (presumably a module-loader library) should be providing it either isn't getting executed or is failing. Given your code, that would have to be somewhere in `application.js`.